I am filtering in Angular, but I cannot get my original data when the input value is empty
In Angular, I am filtering according to the value I enter in the input, but when there is an empty value for the input, my data does not come back.
I get certain data based on the data I entered in the input, but not all data comes back when the input is empty.
applyFilter(value: string) {
    const filterValue = value.trim().toLowerCase();
    const filteredMap = new Map<string, any>();
  
    this._todayShare.forEach((item, key) => {
      
      if (key.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue) ||
        JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)) {
        filteredMap.set(key, item);
      }
    });
  
    this._todayShare = filteredMap;
  }

        <input
          [(ngModel)]="sharedsearchText"
          (keyup)="applyFilter(sharedsearchText)"
          style="width: 50%; margin-top: 1px; margin-bottom: 1px;"
          matInput
          placeholder="Ara..."
        />


Can you add a check in the applyFilter method, if the value is empty simply return from the method.

if(!value) return;
